# jsp How to show “no results found” in modal dialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, jquery-ui

Question:
I have a jsp page such this

```
<form action="MyServlet" method="post" >
      <input type="text" name="word1" >
      <input type="text" name="word2" >
      <input type="text" name="word3" >
      <button type="submit" name="search">Submit</button>
</form>

<table class="table table-bordered">
       <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>word1</th>
              <th>word2</th>
              <th>word3</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>                                      
              <c:forEach items="${words}" var="word">
                 <tr>
                     <td><c:out value="${word.word1}"/></td>
                     <td><c:out value="${word.word2}"/></td>
                     <td><c:out value="${word.word3}"/></td>
                 </tr>
              </c:forEach>
       </tbody>
  </table>
```

This MyServlet class:

```
String word1 = request.getParameter("word1");
String word2 = request.getParameter("word2");
String word3 = request.getParameter("word3");
SearchClass searchClass = new SearchClass();
String search = request.getParameter("search");

if(search !=null) {
  List<Words> words = searchClass.search(word1, word2, word3);
  request.getSession().setAttribute("words", words);
  response.sendRedirect("words.jsp");
}
```

When I click on submit it search on the 3 words and If they found it redirect to the same page that have the form.
But if not found I want to display modal dialog box that tell --- no result found--- How to implement such this dialog?

I try with bootstrap modal but it need data-target!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `<c:choose>` witch is equal to a `switch statement`.

### Explanation

Check if `words` is empty with `test="${empty words}"` and print your message else show the `table` with the results.

### Code

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty words}">
      <p>no results found</p>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <table>
          // ...
        </table>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks @Roman that solve my issue without the need to Modal dialog thanks alot.